# How to use pagination with alaouy/youtube laravel package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using [alaouy/youtube](https://github.com/alaouy/Youtube) package for one of my projects, Its working just fine, But with this method I can't use pagination! Is there any way or I've to write my own code? There is a vendor folder in my resources with pagination folder but I can't get work with it!

```
// List videos in a given channel, return an array of PHP objects
$videoList = Youtube::listChannelVideos('UCk1SpWNzOs4MYmr0uICEntg', 40);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of that package, happy that it was helpful for you and sorry that the documentation wasn't clear enough.
The listChannelVideos is based on the searchAdvanced method, so you can paginate the channel videos like this :

```php
$params = array(
    'channelId'     => 'UCk1SpWNzOs4MYmr0uICEntg',
    'type'          => 'video',
    'part'          => 'id, snippet',
    'maxResults'    => 40);

// Make intial call. with second argument to reveal page info such as page tokens
$search = Youtube::searchAdvanced($params, true);

print_r($search); // First page results

// Check if we have a pageToken
if (isset($search['info']['nextPageToken'])) {
    $params['pageToken'] = $search['info']['nextPageToken'];
}
// Make another call and repeat
$search = Youtube::searchAdvanced($params, true);

print_r($search); // Second page results
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Your package is fantastic, thanks for creating, I'v another question, The return result is not sorted by last or first added video, It's kind of showing the popular video first! I'm guessing it is for the search query? It there any other way around ?

Comment: @Mohib you can add the 'order' => 'date' to the query params and you will get the results sorted by date ;)